# Can you "Ping" a Roblox server?

Tags: node.js, ping, status, roblox

so recently I was making a command for my discord bot (NodeJS), which returns the status and ping of a game server using [Gamedig](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gamedig), but I it doesn't allow me to get status of Roblox servers. I have been googling it, but I could not find anything. So I am asking, is it possible to get the ping/status of a Roblox game server?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my knowledge of the Roblox API, no, this is not possible.

I would recommend that you either work on accessing the API of status.roblox.com or requesting that Roblox become a feature of Gamedig.

Comment: Yeah, from what I found out, Roblox does allow people to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to check if your game specifically is up, you can use the built HTTP service in the Roblox API. Alternatively you could scrape [Roblox Status Page](http://status.roblox.com)